# Can 2 same bundle ID cause any conflict?

Tags: ios, app-id, bundle-identifier

I read from [Cocoa Core Competencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/AppID.html)
that

> An App ID is a two-part string used to identify one or more apps from
>   a single development team. The string consists of a Team ID and a
>   bundle ID search string, with a period (.) separating the two parts.

However it also says that,

> The bundle ID is a unique identifier that identifies a single app and
>   cannot be used by other teams.

I see that we can't register an App ID in the Developer account portal with same bundle ID of an app that is on the appstore.

> An App ID with Identifier 'com.example.myapp' is not available. Please enter a different string.

So I don't know if 2 apps from 2 developers can have same bundle ID (like com.example.MyApp), and if this causes any conflicts?

- Can these 2 apps be installed on the device?
- Can these 2 apps be allowed on the app store?
- How does Push Notification work with these 2 apps ?
- I see that many services like Fabric Crashlytics, Urban Airship, Google App Invites, ... depends on the Bundle ID to differentiate among apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can these 2 apps be installed on the device?

No, it won't. It will replace the existing app.

> Can these 2 apps be allowed on the app store?

No, you cannot create Apps on App Store with same bundle ID.

> How does Push Notification work with these 2 apps ?

Push Notifications will show for the app it is made for whose Push Certificates etc are made

Comment: So, for the device, `ABCDEFG.com.myCompany.myApp` is the same as `MNOPQRS.com.myCompany.myApp` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use same bundle identifier for two different application and try to run on device then previous application is replaced from Device and current application is installed on Device. if you want to run two different application then you can use wild card id.

for App store when you creating application in iTunes connect first it check with existing App ID(same with bundle identifier in Xcode) on app store if exits the you have to put different app id.

Comment: for Appstore, you mean different AppID or BundleID ?

Comment: Nope same it check if bundle identifier not used by any tons of application on app store.

Answer (score 1):

> Can these 2 apps be installed on the device?

No. If you tried to install another application with same bundle ID it will replace the existing one.

> Can these 2 apps be allowed on the app store?

No. When you upload the application on an App store it will ask for unique bundle ID.